# Is it possible to change TSQL Script based on the DB it is being deployed to?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In c# projects there is the concept of Preprocessor Directives that allow you to change what code is compiled depending on whether you are building a debug or release version of the app/dll/etc.  Is there a similar option for TSQL scripts and DB projects?  Specifically, a few of the TSQL scripts I have create dynamic sql statements that do work a remote DB.  There is a different remote DB for development and production so the dynamic SQL needs to be different between the two builds.  It would be nice to not have to manually update the code every time I switch between deploying to dev and deploying to prod.

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dbproj` projects are deployed by VS using [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), so you can use [SQLCmd scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx).

For example:

```
CREATE PROC MyProc
AS
   SELECT * FROM $(ServerVar).$(DbVar).dbo.MyTable
```

You can set these in VS under `Properties/Database.sqlcmdvars` in your .dbproj.

These variables are then substituted into the .sql scripts as it is deployed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a lot of dynamic SQL, I recommend to write your own SP to execute the code - and pass it to the SP via a VARCHAR(MAX) input parameter. Then you use a placeholder instead of your db name - somehting like #DBNAME# and you put in your SP a REPLACE that actually writes the real DB name before executing the code. And you keep your DB names in a parameter table so that your SP can find out which is the right DB name by querying the global variable @@SERVERNAME for example. This has the advantage of running the exact same code in every environement, plus additional benefits that I describe in my blog. https://wordpress.com/post/dimensionalmodelingblog.wordpress.com/92